# Ecplise's jar export error: output container is not accessible

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

Yesterday it was fine, but today I receive that message while exporting library as jar in ecplise

[image]

Please help, thank you

Comment: Refresh the project, if it doesn't work then go to the folder of the project in Explorer and delete the files under bin directory and check.

Comment: Thanks, it helped! Can you post it as an answer? I will mark it as solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refresh the project, if it doesn't work then go to the folder of the project in Explorer and delete the files under bin directory and check